# Gulp source from another task

Tags: gulp

Right now I am creating a temporary file in Gulp which precompiles my templates. After that, I uglify and concat them into one javascript file. But I'd rather not have a temporary files. Is there a way to have a 'dynamic' sources in Gulp? I tried combining streams, but to no avail.

Example code:

```
gulp.task('template', function () {
  gulp.src('./src/tpl/*.hbs')
    .pipe(ember())
    .pipe(concat('tpl.js')) // make sure to only do concat after
    .pipe(gulp.dest('tmp'));
});

gulp.task('uglify', ['template'], function() {
  gulp.src(['./tmp/tpl.js', './src/js/app.js'])
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat('epg.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to put a `return` before `gulp.src` i.e. `return gulp.src(...)` so that the task returns a promise that gets fulfilled when the task is complete.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Tasks can't be piped into other tasks directly, but you can use `event-stream` to merge the streams:

```
var es = require('event-stream');
function template() {
  return gulp.src('./src/tpl/*.hbs')
    .pipe(ember());
}

function appjs() {
  return gulp.src(['./src/js/app.js']);
}

gulp.task('uglify', function() {
  return es.merge(template(), appjs())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat('epg.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: This answer is outdated and incorrect, please see mine where I use `{passthrough: true}` along with gulp.src.

Answer (score 11):

So theoretically you should be able to do this with gulp version 3.8.0 or higher. [Here is the changelog with an example of the feature](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#380).

From the changelog:

> gulp.src is now a writable passthrough, this means you can use it to
>   add files to your pipeline at any point

So your task could be like this:

```
gulp.task('template', function () {
  return gulp.src('./src/tpl/*.hbs')
    .pipe(ember())
    .pipe(concat('tpl.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.src('./src/js/app.js', { passthrough: true }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat('epg.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

<strike>Unfortunately, there seems to be some kind of bug where it has trouble handling certain globs, see the issues mentioned [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/541) and [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/548). Hopefully they'll get that resolved soon. This is preventing me from using this in my project, but in yours you are only adding a single file, so try it out and maybe it will work.</strike>

If it doesn't work, try to use `merge-stream` https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/using-multiple-sources-in-one-task.md

**Edited to include the passthrough option to gulp.src mentioned by Bjorn Tipling**

Comment: Nice solution. +1. Could you clarify this comment: "make sure to only do concat after". Kinda doesn't make sense … Does that mean "after Ember", or "make sure you concat before piping a new source"? Sorry if it's obvious, I just want to make sure I understand.

Comment: @mhulse, I have no idea, you'd have to ask the OP. I was confused about that myself. I just copied from the OP's code. I'll edit my answer to remove that comment, because it is not related to this solution.

Comment: Doh! My bad! I didn't see that until now. Thanks for clarifying and for the answer. :)

Comment: This answer is incorrect, you need `{ passthrough: true }` as a second argument to `gulp.src`, please see my answer below if you need an example.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still coming to this issue you can totally use gulp.src to add additional files into a task mid-stream. You simply need to add `{ passthrough: true }` as an option. Here is a working example:

```
gulp.task(tasks.SASS, () => {
  return gulp.src(paths.css.src)
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.src([ paths.css.vueStyles ], { passthrough: true }))
    .pipe(concat('styles.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.css.dest))
```

The only line that matters to this question is:

```
    .pipe(gulp.src([ paths.css.vueStyles ], { passthrough: true }))
```

These details are unnecessary to the question, but in case there's confusion, I'm taking CSS files built via SASS as part of the task and then concatenating them with SASS files built by webpack (extracted from vue files) in a separate task. My `tasks` and `paths` variables are me not using hard coded strings (most of the time).

Note, I used gulp 4.0 but I don't think this matters, [`passthrough` was added to master in 2015](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl-fs/pull/55)

Comment: Did not work for me with gulp 3, which depends on an old version of vinyl-fs. I had to do `npm install --save-dev vinyl-fs` and replace `gulp.src` with `require('vinyl-fs').src`.